# Sylow Subgroups small question - -shared elements of the $p$-subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have $|G| = 12$. If I have four Sylow $3$-subgroups, why is it that any two elements of the subgroups intersect trivially? Sylow $p$-subgroups are maximal $p$-subgroups meaning that they are not a proper subgroup of any other $p$-subgroup. That means they are never fully contained in another $p$-subgroup.

So why can't it be that there are two elements in each Sylow $3$-subgroup that are shared?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a hint.

Consider a Sylow 3 subgroup $P$. It has order $|P|=3$. Consider a different Sylow 3 subgroup $Q$. It has order $|Q|=3$.

Assume that $|P\cap Q|>1$. Remember, because of Lagrange's theorem, $|P\cap Q|$ is a divisor of $|P|=3$.

So what do you conclude?

Comment: Nice hint: +$1$.

Comment: Since $|P \cap Q|$ divides $3$. As $p$ is prime, $|P \cap Q|$ is $1$ or $p$. But it cannot be $p$ because $P$ and $Q$ must be distinct by the definition of a maximal $p$-group. So $|P \cap Q|$ must be $1$ and therefore their intersection is trivial.

Comment: Exactly! $\quad$